# Why does my camera pick up sound but not video on Ubuntu 12.04? (32bit)

Tags: webcam

I have a Microsoft Lifecam NX-3000 that was working perfectly fine for skype yesterday and so far today skype won't even recognize that I have a camera plugged in.. I tried checking it in cheese too so it's not just skype. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`lsusb` shows I have my camera plugged in and I have tried the following inputs so far:

`sudo apt-get install libv4l-0` and the camera still was not working

and `sudo modprobe v4l1_compat` gave me `FATAL: Module v4l1_compat not found.`

Comment: Try running cheese from the commandline. Do you get any errors?

Comment: The only error it shows is 'No device found'

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and `lsusb`?

Comment: `lsusb` gives - `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0721 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam NX-3000 (UVC-compliant)` and I don't really know what to look for when I put `cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`  I don't see anything about the camera though

Comment: Does the `cat` command give lots of output? If so, add `| grep uvcvideo` to the end of the command and then run it. You don't want any output in this case.

Comment: Ohh, yes it does. I get no output from that command.

Comment: How about `lsmod | grep v4l1_compat` and `lsmod | grep sonixj`?

Comment: Neither gave any output.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using 64 bit Ubuntu. Try this: `sudo apt-get install libv4l-0 lib32v4l-0`. If you're using 32 bit try: `sudo apt-get install libv4l-0`. Then restart.

Comment: I am on 32bit so I tried `sudo apt-get install lib4l-0`and it installed but it still isn't working and my microphone stopped working earlier.

Comment: Run `sudo modprobe v4l1_compat` and reload any programs that might have been using the webcam. Anything change?

Comment: when I run that I get

 `FATAL: Module v4l1_compat not found.`

Comment: Have you tried restarting the system?

Comment: Also please edit your question and include all the test and results so far.

Comment: Hmm. Can you paste the entire contents of `lsmod` to paste.ubuntu.com and give me the link? Thanks.

Comment: Do the camera works in a Live CD?

Comment: I did another reboot and my video is working for now, but my microphone is not. @Seth give me one min and I will do that. I haven't tried a live CD.

Comment: `lsmod` - http://paste.ubuntu.com/6822371/

Comment: Nevermind, the video is not working anymore

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm really lost now..